# JSch SFTP file download containing junk values

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch program to upload and download a file to my SFTP server. When I download the file, the file is containing junk values.

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
public ChannelSftp createSession(String sftpUserName, String sftpHost, int sftpPort) {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp c = null;
    String privateKey = "~/.exec/id_rsa";

    try {
        if (session == null) {
            session = jsch.getSession(sftpUserName, sftpHost, sftpPort);
            //session.setPassword(sftpPassword);
            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
        }
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        c = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return c;
}
public Integer downloadFile(ChannelSftp channelSftp, String FileToBeCopied, String folderPath) {
    int fileDownloaded = -1;

    try {

        //channelSftp.cd(folderPath);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/Users/" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "/Downloads/" + FileToBeCopied);
        channelSftp.setFilenameEncoding("UTF-8");
        channelSftp.get(FileToBeCopied, output);

        fileDownloaded = 0;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        fileDownloaded = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        fileDownloaded = 2;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileDownloaded = 3;

    }
    return fileDownloaded;
}
public boolean uploadFiles(ChannelSftp channelSftp, String workingFile, String ftpRemoteDefaultDirectory, String workingDirectory) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (workingFile != null) {
        if (!workingFile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            try {

                channelSftp.cd(ftpRemoteDefaultDirectory);
                try {
                    File f = new File(workingDirectory + workingFile);
                    //channelSftp.setFilenameEncoding("UTF-8");
                    channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
                    flag = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                destroySession(channelSftp);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I am using MAC. When I have checked online it was mentioned that `OutputStream` will encode the file using "UTF-8" and we don't have to do again.

Comment: Are you sure that the file on the SFTP server is in fact in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yeah it is in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: how to check if if the file is using UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: Notepad++ can be a help there. You can also look at the first few bytes of the file and see it has a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got the information that an `OutputStream` does conversions to UTF-8. No `OutputStream` does that, that's what `OutputStreamWriter` is used for. Also `OutputStream` is an abstract class so when you hold an instance that you only know that it's an `OutputStream` you simply don't know what the stream does with the data. In your code you're using `FileOutputStream` for writing and `FileInputStream` for reading, so there should be no conversion at all of the data being downloaded or uploaded.

So if the data looks wrong after that, the original data doesn't seem to be UTF-8 encoded.

BTW: `channelSftp.setFilenameEncoding("UTF-8");` has nothing to do with the charset/encoding of the data. As the method name suggests, this controls how filenames are encoded, so if it contains non-ASCII-characters you need to set it when downloading and uploaded to make sure that they won't show up corrupted.